# node-github - get user public info

Tags: node.js, github, node-github

I'm trying to fetch some users data for a small research on github by using this api:
https://developer.github.com/v3/users/#get-a-single-user

When I'm trying to fetch user data via **crul** I'm getting the data just by runing this command (without no authentication):

```
curl https://api.github.com/users/<ANY_USER>
```

But when I'm tying to use **[node-github](https://github.com/mikedeboer/node-github)** :

```
var GitHubApi = require("github");
var github = new GitHubApi({...});
github.user.get({
    user: username
}, function(err, res){...});
```

I have authentication problems.

I try to do authentication first :

```
var GitHubApi = require("github");
var github = new GitHubApi({...});
github.authenticate({
    type: "basic",
    username: "MY_USERNAME",
    password: "MY_PASSWORD"
});
github.user.get({
    user: username
}, function(err, res){...});
```

but then I'm getting my user data and not the data for the user I want.

Any idea what is missing here? Why crul is working and github.user.get not? Any better way to do it via nodejs?

Thanks!

Comment: have you tried `github.users.get({user: username},...`

Comment: yes (you can see in code snippets)..

Comment: checkout how I do it in my project: https://github.com/ConfusedDeer/Git-Captain